# Couldn't add Testers in Testflight to a Ready To Test app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Yesterday, I uploaded a Unity game app from Xcode to `TestFlight`, even added the `Test Information` too
[image]
Here is the `External Testers` group page where I'm supposed to see the build to add
[image]
If the app is in processing or review, then I can understand that app store is approving it, but now when the status is `Ready to Test`, then why it is not actually ready to test? Even in main `App Store` page couldn't able to add this build

What's going on? Or what I need to check/test!

Comment: Which option did you choose in Xcode when you uploaded?  You need to choose the App Store option in order for it to be visible to the App Store and external testers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as Paulw11 said in the comment I need to choose the first option saying App Store and  External Testers while uploading from Xcode, otherwise it is just for internal testers only.

Hope it saves someone's time!